PPA warning after upgrading to the latest 24.04 LTS
After I upgraded from 22.04 to the latest 24.04 when I do Update/Upgrade it gives me this warning message:
**/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py:562: Warning: W:https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key 0AB215679C571D1C8325275B9BDB3D89CE49E1 uses weak algorithm (rsa1024) res = self._cache.update(fetch_progress, slist, pulse_interval)** 
I am using Firefox ESR PPA how do you fix this? Do I need to reinstall the PPA or will they fix it with update?
